# ElementNotVisibleException in Selenium during click

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to click a button whose HTML looks like

```
<div class="product-details-options-size clearfix">
   <p>Choose memory capacity </p>
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <div class="active"> <label class="btn plain active"> <input type="radio" name="storageSize" value="32" autocomplete="off" checked="">32GB </label> </div>
      <div class=""> <label class="btn plain "> <input type="radio" name="storageSize" value="128" autocomplete="off">128GB </label> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]
The code for it is:

```
btn = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name='storageSize']")
print("Storage size: ", btn[1].get_attribute('value')) #prints 128
btn[1].click()
```

I am able to print out the value of the button but when I try clicking the same, I get:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the button is a CSS button. From your HTML we can know there is a `Radio button`, but from the page the button is not like a Radio button, it's due to css change the apperence of button to make it not like a Radio button.

Did you noticed there is a Lable near by Radio button, to change apperence of radio button, CSS can place the label at top to cover the Radio button by css : `index`.  No matter how CSS did that. You can't click on the Radio button now, because the Label cover it, you have to click on the Lable.

Why you can print out the button value, because you obtain the button value by `getAtttibute('value')`, If your code change to `print("Storage size: ", btn[1].text)`, it will print empty string.

This is as Selenium Design:

> If an element not visible from user experience, Selenium will report
>   `ElementNotVisible` when click on it, and return empty string when get
>   its text content. Because sendKeys(), click(), getText() will act as user experience.
>
> But getAttribute() not act as user experience, so it not care element is visible or not, once the Tag has your wanted attribute, you can get attribute value.

As I mentioned above, you should click on the label, so change your code to

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(.,'128GB')]").click();
```